# Word for death bringer

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working on a piece of writing where a character dies and death comes and takes him to the afterlife. But my question is, is there a better word for Death—as a character— or Grim Reaper.

I would like something similar that means death bringer. Preferable something on the evil side, not an angel or something.

It is sexless and not an angel but not exactly the devil but feared and "scary" since they bring death. The character appears when someone or something dies and takes them and their soul

Comment: how about just REAPER!

Comment: How about [Charon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charon)?

Comment: **Yama**, the Hindu God of death {https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_death_deities}

Comment: @lbf 's 'Reaper' is pretty darn good ... "harvesting deaths" is plenty evil and understood from the kinda dated 'grim reaper'

Comment: Please describe the character "Death" Is it an angel, a he or she or they sexless? Is the character benevolent or merciless? How do they announce or bring death? Do you want a word that evokes fear, trepidation, resignation or relief?

Comment: Because this is a single word request you should also supply a sentence where this word would be used.

Comment: Would "executor" be too dramatic-sounding? Would you be happy with a verb, noun that is personified?

Comment: I'd say this is a literary request rather than a true request for near-synonyms.

Comment: @Mari-LouA did you *mean* ‘executor’? Seems drily legalistic rather than dramatic...

Comment: Executioner surely...

Comment: @Dan yes, I meant that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black Death [Ovid], Pale Death [Horace], that grim ferryman, that fell sergeant [both Shakespeare], Hell's grim Tyrant [Pope], the king of terrors [Bible], Pale Horse, Pale Rider [Porter]. There are some old references for you that aren't so easy to find googling. Happy hunting, memento mori...haha.

Answer (score 1):

This one is not exactly a word, but more of a metaphor—[**one's last hour**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ones-last-hour):

> the time of one's death

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Hades" as an alternative to "Death" or the word "Stygian" to describe the "Bringer". For examples - Herald of Stygian gloom or Stygian king etc.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Stygian

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hades

Answer (score 0):

**doom**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/doom)

> 1. Inevitable destruction or ruin
> 2. A decision or judgment, especially an official condemnation to a severe penalty.
> 3. Judgment Day.